# Orthographic Camera scales automatically - libgdx

Tags: camera, libgdx, orthographic

I have an orthographic camera in my game that scales things and objects automatically. I don't want it to scale things up. How can I cancel this?

Comment: Need more detail to understand. A camera doesn't scale objects, but it does define how your entire world is scaled to the screen.

Comment: I want the camera to show segments of the world without scaling those. However, it does scales the objects and as a result they get pretty "pixelated" and ugly.

Comment: @DavidLasry if you are showing the entire map on the same space as the map part it needs to be scaled, if not it could never use the same space. What is your exact goal?

Comment: So you have multiple views of different parts of your world? You might just need different cameras with different sizes assigned to them. But really I think we'll need some pictures to understand what you want and what you're getting.